# insert if not exists else update dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes the first one has two columns , the second one has 5 fields , i want to compare the first dataframe with two special column from the second .If it exists i make an update  else i insert the two column in the two special fields . i am new , i need some help to continue thanks

Here what i did

```
package Test

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object TMP_STRUCTURE extends App {

  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop");
  System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/spark-warehouse");

  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("spark session example").getOrCreate()
  //connect to table TMP_STRUCTURE oracle
  val spark = sparkSession.sqlContext
  val df = spark.load("jdbc",
    Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:IPTECH/IPTECH@//localhost:1521/XE",
      "dbtable" -> "IPTECH.TMP_STRUCTURE"))
  df.printSchema()


  val article_groups = spark.load("jdbc", Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gemodb?user=postgres&password=maher",
    "dbtable" -> "article_groups"))

  article_groups.printSchema()

}



root
 |-- CODE: string (nullable = false)
 |-- LIBELLE: string (nullable = false)

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- is_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number: string (nullable = true)
```

i want to comapare code and libelle with id and name based on the column code and id

Any help thanks

Comment: you should also add sample input dataframes and expected dataframes so that others can help you efficiently.

Comment: I just answered a very similar question the other day (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700834/insert-if-not-exists-else-update-in-spark-sql/45811161#45811161). Expand that to two columns and you have your answer :-)